# Reusing React Hooks, Redux Functions and Logic across Desktop and Mobile Components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

We have a website in which we display desktop or mobile versions of components based on the value of 'IsMobile'
`import {isMobileOnly} from "react-device-detect";`

**We started coding the desktop version first and are ready to work on the mobile version. We would like to reuse our redux functions (useSelector and useDispatch), our hooks (useState and useEffect) and functions in such a way that both the Mobile and Desktop versions have access.**

I've looked into HoC's but that seems to be a very limited (and outdated?) approach since basically the only thing that will be different between the Mobile and Desktop versions will be the UI. Are **[custom hooks](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks)** the best approach? Using **one component and 'IsMobile'** logic to differentiate the Desktop and Mobile renderings? **Something else?**

Comment: Just to have a reference for future projects with mobile and desktop versions - https://medium.com/@Vincentxia77/what-is-mobile-first-design-why-its-important-how-to-make-it-7d3cf2e29d00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, I found that **custom hooks** where the best solution to my problem. I had heard of them before, but hadn't really researched what they were about.

Posting this here in case someone else has similar confusion in the future.